# Videojs displaying a custom message without using any plugin

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js

I am trying to display an error message according to a specific condition in  videojs.Is there any possible way of displaying a message without using any plugin like `videojs-errors`?

I have tried using `player.error()` but this only print an error in console but i need it on the player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Video.js's inbuilt modal dialog:

```
player.createModal('Your message here!');
```

https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-modal-dialog.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating an HTML element next to the video tag (not inside) and then placing it on the same container as the video tag? With CSS, absolute positioning and z-index you should be able to put it on top of the player itself.

Comment: I down-voted this answer, because it fails to mention the restriction that my attempts at this approach fail for the case of 'fullscreen' mode. [ If /.when I get my attempt at an alternate approach working, I'll certainly share it here...stay tuned. ]

Answer (score -1):

Luiz wrote (in his answer":   "With CSS, absolute positioning and z-index you should be able to put it on top of the player itself."

I had tried that before myself, but no z-index value would fix the limitation
of not seeing it when in full-screen mode.  That attempt is here: https://weasel.firmfriends.us/HTMLVideoFromCloud/

But then it occurred to me that the ONE approach that would certainly be visible in full-screen is a VTT sub-titles/captions approach. I completed
a prototype for that this morning. It does have a limitation...it
works only in browsers that have full VTT support...i.e. Chrome and Opera.
Both Firefox and Edge don't correctly implement VTT.)

That new prototype is here:
https://weasel.firmfriends.us/DualSubs/

Hope this is helpful.